# WMS layer option with Gemini VA WMS Server on Leaflet

Tags: leaflet, wms

I have got a WMS layer from an instance of Gemini VA WMS Server I want to add to my Leaflet map, version 0.7.7.
For that I need to break down my WMS link to fit the options like this example:

```
var wmsLayer = L.tileLayer.wms('http://demo.opengeo.org/geoserver/ows?', {
    layers: 'nasa:bluemarble'
}).addTo(map);
```

This is the link I am not sure how to use. In QGIS the first line is ID 0 and name "RootLayer". It contain 8 layers and all of them make up the layer I want to add.

The link I have provided is not live but it follows the same structure to the link I got that is working in QGIS.

EDIT: As suggested from comments I tried this:

```
var wmsLayer = L.tileLayer.wms('http://localhost/MapServer/Standard_SDO.wms', {
}).addTo(map);
```

That throws me an error: Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'wms' of undefined.

It seem that it does not like the dot.
Do you know any work around?

This is what I have tried so far but it did not work:

```
var wmsLayer = L.tileLayer.wms('http://localhost/MapServer/ows?', {
        layers: 'Standard_SDO.wms'
    }).addTo(map);
```

Comment: If http://localhost/MapServer/Standard_SDO.wms works with QGIS and is the base-URL where you can read GetCapabilities, then why do you use something different with Leaflet? Much better opportunities with `var wmsLayer = L.tileLayer.wms(http://localhost/MapServer/Standard_SDO.wms?, `

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I tried that but it throw me an error "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'wms' of undefined". In QGIS the first line is ID 0 and name RootLayer". It contain 8 layers and all of them make up the layer I want to add. I does not seem to like the dot notation in the link, leaflet pick it up as a property. Do you know if it is possible to work around it?

Comment: please edit your question to show what you have tried now and what the response is

Comment: What URL do you use to do a GetCapabilities request in a browser?  Is it `http://localhost/MapServer/Standard_SDO.wms?service=WMS&request=GetCapabilities&` is it `http://localhost/MapServer/Standard_SDO.wms/ows?service=WMS&request=GetCapabilities&` or is it something else?

Comment: So this is the live link http://153.110.194.145/GeminiMapServer/VA_Offentlig_Standard_SDO.wms

With GetCapabilities http://153.110.194.145/GeminiMapServer/VA_Offentlig_Standard_SDO.wms?SERVICE=WMS&VERSION=1.1.1&REQUEST=GetCapabilities
&REQUEST=GetCapabilities I am using leaflet version 0.7.7

Answer (score 1):

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'wms' of undefined

That's a weird error, because it means that `L.tileLayer` is `undefined` (when you try to access `L.tileLayer.wms` to call the constructor).

There might be something wrong with the way you're loading Leaflet. Running `console.log(L.tileLayer)` and `console.log(L.tileLayer.wms)` might shed some light on your issue - they should print out a pointer to a `function` [as demonstrated here](https://playground-leaflet.rhcloud.com/det/edit?html,console).

Comment: The other WMS layers load fine, it just this one that cause a problem (the other layers from Geoserver). This is the result from the console log. function(t,e){return new o.TileLayer(t,e)} "o.TileLayer" looks a bit weird to me?

Comment: I was using leaflet 1.0.0! Was meant to use 0.7.7. I used the CDN from your link and got the same log. function(url, options) {
 return new L.TileLayer(url, options);
}  Still the same error though "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'wms' of undefined" Will try something else here

Comment: You must be overwriting or deleting the reference to `L.tileLayer.wms` somehow.

Answer (score 0):

This is a working sample I hope it helps:

```
var map = L.map('map', {
    crs: L.CRS.EPSG3857,
    center: [5399596.405931242, 4137884.567863098],
    zoom: 3
});

var wmsLayer = L.tileLayer.wms('../server-side/wms.php?layerId=708', {
    CRS: L.CRS.EPSG3857,
}).addTo(map);
```